# Flow: constructor call. Constructor cannot be called on type `X`

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have this weird errors with flow that I can't find in my project:

> Error:(63, 18) Flow: constructor call. Constructor cannot be called on
>   type `Error`

and its pointing me to file in `node_modules/fbjs/lib/fetchWithLibraries.js.flow`.

Error type in `flow-typed` directory:

```
type Error = { [key: string]: string | string[] | Error }; 
declare type AxiosFailure = { status: number, data: Error };
```

[image: error]

I don't know what am I looking for.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you post the entire error output?

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's the whole error, see the Image I added.

Comment: To me, this seems like a terrible error message from Flow. It doesn't seem to be pointing to the line that actually uses `Error`, just the line where it is declared? Are you potentially doing `class Example extends Error` or `new Error()` somewhere that you've imported that Axios `Error` somewhere? It sounds like it thinks you are using `new` to construct one of those `Error`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth well... I have a component with name Error. Maybe its conflicting with global type Error somewhere somehow? I will look into project for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the name of the type to `ErrorObject` and problem disappeared. Probably it was conflicting with component with the same name.